# How to add a submit button to react-native-image-uploader

Tags: php, react-native

**Hi**, I am using this extension [Image-Uploader-in-React-Native](https://github.com/Sir-hennihau/Image-Uploader-in-React-Native) which is using react-native-uploader and react-native-image-picker, **When** I chose an image from the library or taking an image from the camera it will be submitted directly to the server (php Backend).
**How** can I implement a "Submit Button" so I can send it manually to the server? 
**And** How can I dismiss the image and the textField content after uploading is completed. 
**Kindly**, Also if possible please How to implement a progress bar for the Uploading Progress?
**__** Please note I'm `totallyBeginner();` with React-Native :)

**Thanks in Advance ...**

Answer (score 0):

i think this library is exactly what you need 'react-native-upload' 
https://github.com/aroth/react-native-uploader .

Comment: I already using it, But I don't know how to implement the submit button!!. Can you please help me ?

Comment: here is an example shows how to implement 
https://github.com/aroth/react-native-uploader/blob/master/examples/UploadFromCameraRoll/index.ios.js

Comment: Please if you could have a look at my code https://pastebin.com/6rGMBvV9

Comment: Hello, Any Updates! <3